# How can i add a infowindow on markers loaded form a XML file

Tags: jquery, xml, google-maps-api-3

Can someone tell me how i can add a info window on markers loaded from a Xml file.

This is the code I'm using to load the markers.

```
google.load("maps", "3",  {other_params:"sensor=false"});
google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");

function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.132633, 5.2912659999999505);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    jQuery.get("locaties.xml", {}, function(data) {
        jQuery(data).find("marker").each(function() {
            var marker = jQuery(this);
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
                parseFloat(marker.attr("lat")),
                parseFloat(marker.attr("lng"))
            );
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: latlng, map: map});
        });
    });
}
function loadScript() {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}

window.onload = loadScript;

google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
```

this is the XML file;

```
<markers>
<marker lat="52.08920341101735" lng="4.279875700000048" />
<marker lat="52.083408210994186" lng="4.314160399999992"/>
<marker lat="52.08598371100446" lng="4.301652100000069"/>
</markers>
```

Comment: Do the markers work? (I can't spot anything that should not work) If yes, you add the infowindows the exact same way like the markers were not loaded from XML.

Answer (score 0):

After you create the marker, all you need to do is to assign the infowindow:

```
jQuery.get("locaties.xml", {}, function(data) {
    jQuery(data).find("marker").each(function() {
        var markerXML = jQuery(this);
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
            parseFloat(markerXML.attr("lat")),
            parseFloat(markerXML.attr("lng"))
        );
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: latlng, map: map});

        // now that the marker is placed, assign event listener on the marker
        // and create/assign infowindow to the event trigger.
        markerInfoWindow(marker, markerXML.attr("info"));
    });
});

// ..... other code here .....

// the marker event handler onclick and infowindow creation/assignment 
function markerInfoWindow(marker, information){
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: information
        });
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks fore your advise but i cant seem to get it to work. the problem is i would like to place the text inside the information window in my XML file like this;<markers>
<marker lat="52.08920341101735" lng="4.279875700000048" info="The information in the window here" />
<marker lat="52.08920341101735" lng="4.279875700000048" info="The information in the window here2" />
<marker lat="52.08920341101735" lng="4.279875700000048" info="The information in the window here3" />
</markers>

Comment: @Stefan, I've updated my answer. See if it fits your requirements.

Comment: Thanks again but i still can't get it to work. The information windows won't i don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: @Stefan, well, you could start by debugging... place alerts "all over", see if the events are fired, use firefox's firebug to help you debug javascript and make sure there are no errors..